Usage Of SQLAlchemy With Declarative Base Automap Extension
We are running the database migrations using Liquibase and Sqlalchemy to access the database tables in our lambda with the automap extension.
engine = Database._get_engine(rds_client=rds_client)
base = automap_base()
base.prepare(autoload_with=engine, schema=Database._schema, reflect=True)

and then access the tables using base -
User = base.classes.user 

As we don't have any table schema in the code, the development is a challenge without any autosuggestions.
The first option is to use the DeclarativeBase for the table schema described below but I am not sure of the side effects of the conflict/mismatch in the schema.
engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:password@localhost/postgres')

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"

    id = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = mapped_column(String(50), nullable=False)
    fullname = mapped_column(String)
    lastname = mapped_column(String)
    nickname = mapped_column(String(30))

Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine, checkfirst=True)

The other options is to use the mix of both by DeferredReflection described here https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/declarative_tables.html#using-deferredreflection
Is anyone using Sqlalchemy with an external migration tool? How to manage the table schema with an external migration tool? What are the best practices around it?

I would rather use fastapi+sqlmodel

I have no real-world experience with this scenario, so I won't answer, but I would have thought using a code generator like sqlacodegen and diff-ing the output after each migration might be one way to do it. Especially if you could automate generating git patches from the generated code (assuming you are using git).
